# -webkit-transform: translateY not working in Safari

Tags: css, webkit, transform

I'm having trouble making `transform: translateY` work in Safari unless I write it as `-webkit-transform: -webkit-translateY`, which I understand is how older versions of the browser read it but I'm using the most recent version of the browser. Also, when I do this, it stops working as expected in Chrome. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Have you tried writing both of them? Like this:
transform: translateY
-webkit-transform: -webkit-translateY
But on separate lines

Comment: Does the value `-webkit-translateY` exist? I think it should be `-webkit-transform: translateY`. Please tell us which version of Safari do you use?

Comment: @ David Wolters Yeah and when I did it broke in Safari again :\

Comment: I'm using version 10. I read somewhere that -webkit-translateY was how it use to be written and now it's just translateY? That's where I go the idea to do it but when I did, the issue I mentioned in my post occurred.

Comment: Safari 10 doesn't need prefix for that just remove them all and try.

Comment: You mean just transform: translateY?

Comment: What you need to do is provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/zug673b4/) and it works in all browsers that I tested; now I don't have Safari 10 here, but it does work in v5.1. And all other browsers.